# C# how to send & receive from a hardware protocol?

Tags: c#, hardware

I'm a C# programmer and I know nothing about hardware protocol things.
today I received a document that is some protocols of a Lock hardware, like this:

**lock command**

```
start 0x80
board address 0x01-0xf
lock address 0x00-18
command 0x33
verify code XX
```

**sample:**

```
machine send 0x80 0x01 0x01 0x33 0xB2 

if recieve 0x80 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x91 (means unlock)

if receive 0x80 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x80 (means locked)
```

All I want to know is, if C# can handle these commands? if can, where I can have a quick start, or what should I search on google?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. C# can handle this. This is call `polling`. Basically, the idea is

send command, receive reply, substring information that you need (in your case, most probably the last 2 bytes) and perform some function on it. I'm not sure if you understand but I'll give you an example on something I've done previously but this is `event` where data is send to machine whenever event is triggered.

```
public enum Transaction
{
  LOCK = 0x01,
  UNLOCK
};

private static string getTransactionDescription(Transaction transaction, string data = "")
    {
        string result = "";
 switch (transaction)
 {
   case Transaction.UNLOCK:
   case Transaction.LOCK:
    var slot = ByteOperation.reverse4ByteBitPattern(data.Substring(32, 64));
    for (int i = 8 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if ((Convert.ToInt32(ByteOperation.ToggleEndian_4Bytes(slot.Substring(i * 8, 8)), 16) & (1 << j)) > 0)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
                {
                    result += ", ";
                }
                result += "Slot " + (((7 - i) * 8) + j + 1).ToString("D3");
            }
        }
    }
    break;
}
return result;
```

Comment: why this answer -1?

Comment: @OhMyDog I have no idea why is this voted down but I can tell you that the above code is cropped from my own project so it is not something that doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: anyway I've used SerialPort to solved my problem, thank you very much.